# Path for image on button using Oracle ADF Mobile

Tags: css, oracle-adf, oracle-adf-mobile

I'm trying to append an image on button, how do I place image for button using CSS?

This is the CSS I'm using for button:

```
.amx-commandButton .btnSample{background: url("../Login/login1.png") ;
  background-image: inherit; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: center; }
```

`login1.png` is image present in `Login` folder. This image is not being appended on button.

This is button declaration in amx file:

```
<amx:commandButton text="" id="cb1" action="login"
                   inlineStyle="color:White; height:42px; width:120px;" styleClass="btnSample"
                   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
background-image:url('../FARs/ProjectName/public_html/skins/images/icons/disclosureArrow.png')
```

All verify that file exists in the that path from your deployment folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try This : 
... inlineStyle="position:center;" **icon="**/1.jpg"/>